# How do I control element to not getting error?

Tags: javascript, jquery

my code gave me a error when I remove `data-other-placeholder` attribute from my input:text like you see below:

> "message": "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of
>   undefined",

I have a control with if statement after jquery plugin as you can see if you look at..

```js
   
(function($) {
  "use strict";

  $.fn.placeholderTypewriter = function(options) {

    // Plugin Settings
    var settings = $.extend({
      delay: 50,
      pause: 1000,
      text: [],
      loop: true
    }, options);

    // Type given string in placeholder
    function typeString($target, index, cursorPosition, callback) {

      // Get text
      var text = settings.text[index];

      // Get placeholder, type next character
      var placeholder = $target.attr('placeholder');
      $target.attr('placeholder', placeholder + text[cursorPosition]);

      // Type next character
      if (cursorPosition < text.length - 1) {
        setTimeout(function() {
          typeString($target, index, cursorPosition + 1, callback);
        }, settings.delay);
        return true;
      }

      // Callback if animation is finished
      callback();
    }

    // Delete string in placeholder
    function deleteString($target, callback) {

      // Get placeholder
      var placeholder = $target.attr('placeholder');
      var length = placeholder.length;

      // Delete last character
      $target.attr('placeholder', placeholder.substr(0, length - 1));

      // Delete next character
      if (length > 1) {
        setTimeout(function() {
          deleteString($target, callback)
        }, settings.delay);
        return true;
      }

      // Callback if animation is finished
      callback();
    }

    // Loop typing animation
    function loopTyping($target, index) {

      // Clear Placeholder
      $target.attr('placeholder', '');

      // Type string
      typeString($target, index, 0, function() {

        // Up index
        index = index + 1;

        // If loop is false, just run through the array once
        if (index === settings.text.length && !settings.loop) {
          return false;
        }

        // Pause before deleting string
        setTimeout(function() {

          // Delete string
          deleteString($target, function() {
            // Start loop over
            loopTyping($target, index % settings.text.length)
          })

        }, settings.pause);
      })

    }

    // Run placeholderTypewriter on every given field
    return this.each(function() {

      loopTyping($(this), 0);
    });

  };

}(jQuery));

$(function() {


  var placeTarget = $(".search-hotels"),
    dataValue = placeTarget.attr("placeholder"),
    getPlaceholder = placeTarget.data("other-placeholder");
  if (getPlaceholder.length > 0 || getPlaceholder !== undefined) {
    var splitData = getPlaceholder.split("|"),
      targetText = [dataValue];
    var placeholderText = splitData;

    if ((dataValue == "") || (dataValue == undefined)) {
      placeTarget.placeholderTypewriter({
        text: placeholderText,
        delay: 70,
        loop: false,
      });
    } else {
      placeTarget.placeholderTypewriter({
        text: targetText,
        delay: 70,
        loop: false,
      });
    }
  }
});
```

```css
input {
  padding: 12px;
  border: 3px solid #ccc;
  margin: 30px auto;
  display: block;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="search-hotels" placeholder="Hi I am a default placeholder that you've seen" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: If you removed the attribute, then trying to get it by `data()` will return `null`. Try this: `if (getPlaceholder && getPlaceholder.length > 0)`

Comment: Uhm you should definitelyy first check if `getPlaceholder` is undefined an then if its length is 0, not the opposite. Edit: yeah, as DontVoteMeDown said it will work.

Comment: @nonzaprej that's the point!

Comment: I was still writing the comment, dude!! D:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two issues:

1. `getPlaceholder !== undefined` doesn't check if the value is an array.
2. You have to check if both conditions are fulfilled, if the first is not, the second is not evaluated.

```js
   
(function($) {
  "use strict";

  $.fn.placeholderTypewriter = function(options) {

    // Plugin Settings
    var settings = $.extend({
      delay: 50,
      pause: 1000,
      text: [],
      loop: true
    }, options);

    // Type given string in placeholder
    function typeString($target, index, cursorPosition, callback) {

      // Get text
      var text = settings.text[index];

      // Get placeholder, type next character
      var placeholder = $target.attr('placeholder');
      $target.attr('placeholder', placeholder + text[cursorPosition]);

      // Type next character
      if (cursorPosition < text.length - 1) {
        setTimeout(function() {
          typeString($target, index, cursorPosition + 1, callback);
        }, settings.delay);
        return true;
      }

      // Callback if animation is finished
      callback();
    }

    // Delete string in placeholder
    function deleteString($target, callback) {

      // Get placeholder
      var placeholder = $target.attr('placeholder');
      var length = placeholder.length;

      // Delete last character
      $target.attr('placeholder', placeholder.substr(0, length - 1));

      // Delete next character
      if (length > 1) {
        setTimeout(function() {
          deleteString($target, callback)
        }, settings.delay);
        return true;
      }

      // Callback if animation is finished
      callback();
    }

    // Loop typing animation
    function loopTyping($target, index) {

      // Clear Placeholder
      $target.attr('placeholder', '');

      // Type string
      typeString($target, index, 0, function() {

        // Up index
        index = index + 1;

        // If loop is false, just run through the array once
        if (index === settings.text.length && !settings.loop) {
          return false;
        }

        // Pause before deleting string
        setTimeout(function() {

          // Delete string
          deleteString($target, function() {
            // Start loop over
            loopTyping($target, index % settings.text.length)
          })

        }, settings.pause);
      })

    }

    // Run placeholderTypewriter on every given field
    return this.each(function() {

      loopTyping($(this), 0);
    });

  };

}(jQuery));

$(function() {


  var placeTarget = $(".search-hotels"),
    dataValue = placeTarget.attr("placeholder"),
    getPlaceholder = placeTarget.data("other-placeholder");
  if (getPlaceholder instanceof Array && getPlaceholder.length > 0) {
    var splitData = getPlaceholder.split("|"),
      targetText = [dataValue];
    var placeholderText = splitData;

    if ((dataValue == "") || (dataValue == undefined)) {
      placeTarget.placeholderTypewriter({
        text: placeholderText,
        delay: 70,
        loop: false,
      });
    } else {
      placeTarget.placeholderTypewriter({
        text: targetText,
        delay: 70,
        loop: false,
      });
    }
  }
});
```

```css
input {
  padding: 12px;
  border: 3px solid #ccc;
  margin: 30px auto;
  display: block;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="search-hotels" placeholder="Hi I am a default placeholder that you've seen" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Sometimes it's better to explain what's wrong and just write the correction to the wrong parts of code instead of rewriting the whole code corrected.

Comment: @nonzaprej I think I clearly mentioned what is wrong.

Comment: Wait you edited the answer, right? I'm always late with comments... Either that or I'm blind.

Comment: @nonzaprej yep I changed it 30 seconds after posting. But in the original post I also adressed the problem.

Comment: but plugin doesn't work anymore ? I mean I had a placeholder with animation it was work if `data-other-placeholder` set with array

Comment: then the issue is not caused by that, more likely by the fact that other-placeholder might not be an array?

Comment: so I have a this error: https://codepen.io/cowardguy/pen/VbJNxj?editors=1010  `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined` and I have no any if statement?

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WjqBZW?editors=1011 look at this. the problem is that other-placeholder doesn't exist. check your code please

Comment: Great, glad to help you